# Can I replace sugar with cane syrup in sourdough recipe

Tags: bread, sugar, sourdough, starter

I'm baking my own sourdough bread (whole wheat-rye). Recipe calls for adding 2 table spoons of sugar with a bit of milk to get the starter, well... started.

I thought about replacing it with cane syrup (unsulfered molasses) as it contains more micronutriens. Is this a good idea?

Comment: have you got an existing starter or is this sugar and milk going into the initial starter?

Comment: @worthwords existing starter. I later set a side part of dought for next round of baking.

Comment: Where rye is concerned, you are usually better off using molasses than granulated sugar of any description. I'm not sure why, but the family recipes I have for rye baking all insist on molasses or honey. The same applies if you use barley.

Comment: @Shalryn probably because receipt's origin is in central Europe, where sugar is made out of sugar beets and molasses is uneatable for humans, it calls for sugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been baking with honey and molasses for some time now and I see no much differences except that dough and bread gets much dark brown colour.